# How to reduce a large Magento 2 installation?

Tags: magento2, cache, server-setup, optimization, backup

I'm using Magento 2.4 and my installation is using 200GB, I'd like to reduce it.

**I want to remove old logs, backups, caches, duplicated images and etc.**

How could I optimize it?

Answer (score 1):

All the ones you mention are worth being looked at. I may have some more for you to take a look:

in **pub** folder, it is useful to remove files that are not meant to be there and **pub** is often misused.

1. Right away, find files that are larger than 5M is good place to start. They may be legitimate files. However, by doing just this, I once found an image that was a malware at the time.

this command will list these big files for you (this command assumes you are in a terminal at the pub folder of your magento site)

```
find . -type f -size +5M
```

2. Find the images for which products have been deleted. There are scripts out there performing query for doing this search but I have not used any since Magento 2 came
3. find images that are quite big and may not be needed:

   find . -name "*png" -type f -size +2M

   find . -name "*jpg" -type f -size +2M
4. files that may have been created during development. I doubt it is your case but possibly worth a try:

find . -name "*sql" -type f

find . -name "*zip" -type f

find . -name "*gz" -type f

5. although it is less common, this same practice can apply to vendor folder and app folder. As you know, these folders do contain the modules for your site. I have come across modules creating export files and these could amount to large amount of space. The command below would list the possible files

   find . -name "*csv" -type f

Comment: Also **var/** folder. Arcive old logs. Remove old import/export logs

Comment: Definitely, I have just listed the possibility that Rafael has not listed. Var/session for instance can be massive if not cleared by the os, thanktfor your comment